# Is there any K-means++ implementation outside of scikit-learn for Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn, k-means

I have nothing against scikit-learn, but I had to install anaconda to get it, which is a bit obtrusive.

Comment: For example in [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.vq.html). But some people are telling that is supers-slow. (The reason scipy and to a lesser extens scikit-learn are not that easy to install on some systems like windows is the need for speed -> cython, blas, fortran  there are many tools used to improve speed; i would always prefer the *installing anaconda* way giving you the chance to use the best tool through easy setups!)

Comment: kmeans in scipy does not implement kmeans++, it samples randomly, runs multiple samplings, and returns the best result.

Comment: My bad. i didn't read it carefully!. But the initialization in kmeans++ is so simple, that you can implement it yourself. I would still stick to scikit-learn, but well...

Comment: I did (in python) but it's kinda slow; I guess I'll stick to Anaconda, maybe implement this: http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol5/p622_bahmanbahmani_vldb2012.pdf

Comment: @Eduardo I've implemented it before, it runs reasonably fast and should run on python 2.7 (I've only ever used it on py3, so no guarantees): https://github.com/tttthomasssss/clustering/blob/master/cosine_means.py#L72.

Comment: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4119 intended to implement kmeans++ in scipy.cluster, but it stalled on waiting for the OP. If someone picks up the PR and finishes it up, there's a high chance it'll be accepted.

Comment: Very cool, Thomas

Answer (score 0):

So, the situation as of today is: there is no distributed Python implementation of KMeans++ other than in scikit-learn. That situation may change if a good implementation finds its way into scipy.